# How to code PHP to display all files from Google Cloud Storage

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Now I had done the php code to upload file to google cloud storage

```html
<?php  
use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;  
$bucket = '<your bucket name>'; // your bucket name  
$root_path = 'gs://' . $bucket . '/';  
$_url = '';  

if(isset($_POST['submit']))  
{  
    if(isset($_FILES['userfile']))  
    {  
        $name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];  
        $file_size =$_FILES['userfile']['size'];  
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];  
        $original = $root_path .$name;  
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $original);  
        $_url=CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl($original);
    }  
}  
  
?>  
    <html>  
  
    <body>  
        <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> Send these files:  
            <p/> <input name="userfile" type="file" />  
            <p/> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="UPLOAD" /> </form>  
    </body>  
  
    </html>  
    <?php  
  
echo $_url;  
  
?>
```

Then I would like to code another php to display all files in my bucket on Google Storage. But, I don't know how to Please help and guide me

Answer (score 0):

This code will allow you to check all the files in a given bucket in your project, including the ones in a subfolder.

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;
$projectId = 'PROJECT-ID';

$bucketName = 'YOUR-BUCKET';
$storage = new StorageClient([    
'projectId' => $projectId
]);
$bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
$listObjects = $bucket->objects(['fields' => 
    'items/name,nextPageToken'
]);
foreach ($listObjects as $item) {           
    echo $item->name() . PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

You can see more options for this client library in [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.57.1/storage/bucket?method=objects)